# Value between or search in range and return value in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Hi All,

I have a table for employee scores levels (Table D1 to F6), there is points for each level, for example score (4.60) will be in the 3rd level which has (3) points.

I want to write a formula in the column (B) to check in the table an return the point value from the column F, You can see the examples in D2 & D3.

Regards
Adel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is one of the most awesome functions ever invented... `VLOOKUP`

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$D$2:$F$6,3, TRUE)
```

(Paste in `B2` and drag down)

Quick explanation of the arguments.

1. `A2` is the value we're going to be looking up in the table
2. `$D$2:$F$6` is the "table" we're going to be looking up. It's going to search the first column of it (You could have anything you wanted in Column `D`, VLOOKUP Only looks at the first column).
3. `3` is the column number of our table that contains the answers we want to be looking up, and returning (in this case, `F`).
4. `TRUE` means we want to search ranges, not just exact values. If it was `FALSE` then we'd only get the numbers we wanted if we entered the precise scores.

Of course, using this method, there isn't any upper bounds to it, a value of say 20 would give us the last row (i.e. 5 points), however, you could fix this easily using an `IF` statement.

```
=IF(A2 > $E$6, "N/A", VLOOKUP(A2,$D$2:$F$6,3, TRUE))
```

This could of course be done a bit neater if you believed you were going to be adding more rows to the table later, but it works for now.

Comment: Thank you very much, but the value in (A2) is not fixed, it can be in range! for example A2 = 7.50, this value is not there in the other table but it is in the range, look at row 5 please, you will find the value 7.50 between (D5 & E5), so 7.50 will be between (7 to 8.99) so the value of B2 will take F5 which is (4) ....

Comment: By setting the final argument of `VLOOKUP` to `TRUE`, you're asking it to look in ranges, so, if in your case you have the value `7` which is worth 4 points and the next value is `9`, `VLOOKUP` will round an input of 7.5 (or any number less than 9, including 8.99999) down to 7 and return 4 points. Try testing it on your set and see if it's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Below formula in cell B2:

```
 =VLOOKUP(A2,$D$2:$F$6,3, TRUE)
```

Comment: Value returned is (1) and this is not correct, because 7.50 is in the range of the row 5, so the value returned should be 4 ....

Comment: @adelShehri its weird I got value (4).