# What excel formula to type

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am doing an excel sheet for grading system and following is the grade system:

Percentage grade:------------(90-100% )-----------( 80-89%)---------------- (70-79%)---------------------------
Letter Grade:--------------------(   A  )-----------------------( B )-----------------------( C )-----------------------------

Now, if cell "a1 = 83" than I wanted cell "a2 = B"
or if cell "a1 becomes 95" than cell "a2" should become "A" automatically.

I tried this formula: (it didn't work)
=(IF(70>a1<79,"C",)),(IF(80>a1<89,"B",)),(IF(90>a1<100,"A",))

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `70>a1<79` doesn't look correct, I think you mean `70<a1<79`

Comment: For this formula to work, you have to split the comparison: `IF(AND(70 < a1,a1 < 79), ...`

Answer (score 5):

Your formula is close, but Excel cannot perform two relational operations in one shot. Instead you have to split it up in an `AND` statement.

This should work:

```
= IF(AND(70<=A1,A1<80),"C",IF(AND(80<=A1,A1<90),"B",IF(90<=A1,"A")))
```

Or for a shorter solution, you can do this:

```
= IF(A1>=90,"A",IF(A1>=80,"B",IF(A1>=70,"C")))
```

---

**EDIT**

Even shorter, completely different method:

```
= MID("CBA",MATCH(A1,{70,80,90},1),1)
```

---

**EDIT**

Just thought of another one, shorter still:

```
= MID("CBAA",A1/10-6,1)
```

Comment: I like that `MID` version - although had to change `70`, `80` & `90` to `0.7`, `0.8` and `0.9`.  Just noticed your second version is same as mine but in reverse order - sorry, thinking I should delete mine now.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I think your post is good. It adds value to the answers. I didn't even think of the `%`. Whether to use `90` or `0.9` depends on how the user has the cells formatted.

Answer (score 1):

You want to check the numbers in order:

- If A1 is blank then display a blank.
- If A1 is less than 80% then show "C".
- If A1 is less than 90% then show "B".
- Any other value will be higher than this so show "A".

Translated to a formula:
`=IF($A$1="","",IF($A$1<0.8,"C",IF($A$1<0.9,"B","A")))`

Answer (score -1):

If possible, split the table of scores/grades into:

LowerScore | UpperScore | Grade

```
70          79          C

80          89          B

90         100          A
```

The use a VLOOKUP formula:

=VLOOKUP(B6,$A$2:$C$3,3,TRUE)

Where B6 is the cell your are inputting your score to, (e.g. the 83).

See here for a very similar question: [Value between or search in range and return value in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272381/value-between-or-search-in-range-and-return-value-in-excel)

Comment: Seems like overkill to use a helper table for such a simple problem.

Answer (score -2):

Use index and match (or Lookup).